# Выйти в тираж

Tags: фразеология

Так говорят о прекращении чего-либо или списании со счетов. А почему, собственно, так говорят? Тираж - это количество экземпляров печатного издания, по крайней мере, я знаю только это значение.
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://russo.com.ua/istoriya_slov/page/vyiyti_v_tiraj.232

Французское слово tirage (буквально: «вытаскивание») вошло в русский язык в начале XIX в. Оно обозначало жеребьевку, вынимание жребия для той части облигаций выигрышного займа или иного рода обязательства, которая должна быть погашена в этот раз путем возврата стоимости облигаций их владельцам, а также розыгрыш выигрышей в займе или лотерее.

Это выражение приобрело особую экспрессивную значительность в 60—70-х годах XIX в. в стилях буржуазной литературной речи. А. С. Суворин в очерках «На бирже и у господ плутократов» изображает сон буржуазной дамы: «Он схватил меня за руку и, потрясая ее, произнес: «Я выхожу в тираж! Я несчастный билет — я выхожу в тираж: я тебя не достоин».

С  этим выражением в русском литературном языке последней трети XIX в. связывается целый ряд переносных значений: а) Получить отставку, потерять служебное значение'; б) перестать пользоваться вниманием, уважением, стать устарелым, например:

«Переплетчик Мейер уже вышел в тираж: он служит при тюрьмах». "Старик… потирает поясницу и угнетённо вздыхает. Он жалок в своей беспомощности, тем более, что ещё верит в свою работоспособность и не хочет выходить в тираж (Мамин-Сибиряк)

Современное значение слова «тираж»  (количество экземпляров печатного издания одного выпуска  и  (разг.)  все экземпляры этого выпуска)   является вторичным, изменение шло  по схеме:  тираж-розыгрыш → количество лотерейных   билетов в таком тираже → количество экземпляров  любой печатной продукции.

Comment: Действительно, *тираж* в 19 веке понимался однозначно :  
>ТИРАЖ
 (фр. tirage, от tirer - вытягивать, тянуть). 1) розыгрыш лотереи. 2) вынутие процентных бумаг для погашения их, т. е. оплаты.

>(Источник: "Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка". Чудинов А.Н., 1910)

>ТИРАЖ
 розыгрыш лотереи для номеров тех билетов, на которые падают выигрыши, или номеров тех %% бумаг, которые подлежат выкупу и уничтожению (т. погашения).

>(Источник: "Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка". Павленков Ф., 1907)

Comment: А при чем здесь однозначность?  

У Вас даже в цитате два значения.
И что интересно - источники из 20 века. )))

Answer (score 1):

> Тираж - это количество экземпляров печатного издания, по крайней мере, я знаю только это значение.

И еще сам факт выхода издания - вплоть до поступления на прилавок. Но тут вряд ли есть реальная связь, хотя некую аналогию при желании можно найти и тут.

Вернее все-таки разобраться насчет тиража как розыгрыша призов лотерей и подобных вещей.
Перво-наперво надо очень четко разделить современную лотерею и облигацию (и подобный ей бумаги) займа - как его понимали лет полтораста-двести назад.
Версия о связи с тиражом ***лотерейным*** весьма и весьма сомнительна. Поскольку никогда проведение такого тиража "выходом" не называли, да и "выход в тираж" означало бы выпадение приза на данный лотерейный билет, а совсем не обесценивание его.

А вот процедура ***погашения облигаций*** путем тиражного розыгрыша в прошлом была несколько иной, отличной даже от процедуры погашения облигаций кому-то еще памятных послевоенных госзаймов, хотя и близкой к ней. 
В самом исходном понимании подобная облигация приносила доход (подобно проценту со вклада), но - ровно до момента выпадения в тираж. А после попадания в тираж подлежала погашению по номиналу. 
Т.е. в определенном смысле обесценивалась, хотя и давала возможность фиксировать возврат вложенного. Вот этот смысл и вкладывался  в выражение.

Большинство современных источников вообще упускают или невнятно излагают эту самую важную для понимания деталь: имеется в виду тираж ***погашения*** ценной бумаги, займа, а не просто лотерейного розыгрыша призов. Так уж получилось, что форма такого заимствования себя изжила, а выражение осталось. Отсюда, видимо, и непонятки.

Answer (score 0):

Как мне видится, это словосочетание - ни что иное,как обычное сленговое выражение определённого круга людей (по-видимому литераторов), для которых оно могло означать завершение работы:"Всё, в тираж!" - мог бы сказать главный редактор, изучивший очередную, предложенную к изданию рукопись и, забыв о ней, взяться за работу над следующей.